# Creating .Net Standard project for Visual C++ (VS 2017) that I can use in WPF and UWP

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-c++, uwp, .net-standard

In Visual Studio 2017 you can create a ".NET Standard Library" project for C# (to be able to reference the dll in WPF and UWP). Unfortunately there is no template for Visaul C++ to do this. I need a wrapper to a native C++ library that I can use in WPF aswell as UWP.

How can I setup such a project in Visual Sudio 2017?

Comment: You can't.  .NET Standard is currently only defined for .NETCore projects.  A million miles removed from WPF and C++.  You'll have to create two wrappers, a managed one in C++/CLI that you can use in WPF and an unmanaged one in C++/CX that you can use in UWP.